# scan.setTimeRange get timeout hbase java

Tags: java, hbase

I am trying to scan hbase table with `scan.setTimeRange(x,y)` and my java program timeouts.

If I remove the `scan.setTimeRange(x,y)` it works.

1. How can I solve it?
2. Are there other options to filter on time with scan in hbase?

Comment: Please show the exact code at least, and copy paste the relevant part of the exception. Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi I solve it by increase the value of rpc timeout. Thanks for the help